# Loop typing "gm" in a discord server I do not own

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui, anaconda3

I am trying to write a type bot to type "gm" in a discord server that I do not own.

The server has a cool down period of 5 minutes (I need to wait five minutes between two "gm"s)

I am new to python, and I watched some tutorials on how to code simple bot. I tried to combine several codes for my purpose.

I am using `pyautogui`, `time`, `pynput` and `thread`, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
import pyautogui
import random


TOGGLE_KEY = KeyCode(char="t") # Set a toggle key for the program

typing = False  #variable starts as false, to avoid bugs


def typer():
    while True:
        if typing:
            time.sleep(5)
            pyautogui.write("gm")
            time.sleep(1) #One second pause, to not look like a bot
            pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(random.randint(310, 500))  #Here I set a random interval over 5 minutes, to not look like a bot


def toggle_event(key):
    if key == TOGGLE_KEY:
        global typing
        typing = not typing


type_thread = threading.Thread(target=typer)
type_thread.start()

with Listener(on_press=toggle_event) as listener:
    listener.join()
```